# Sind/ist Verbindung mit UND – Plural ausreichend?

Tags: grammatical-number

Ich bin mir bezüglich des **sind** unsicher. Kann man folgenden Satz so schreiben oder müsste man hier noch ein **ist** nach **Anwendung** einfügen?

> Alle Funktionen **sind** schon konfiguriert und die Anwendung damit sofort nutzbar.

Answer (score 6):

Ich bin jetzt nicht sicher, ob es irgendwo festgeschriebene Regeln gibt, die in genau so einem Fall greifen. Und selbst wenn es solche Regeln gäbe, hat dennoch immer der tatsächliche Gebrauch der Sprache Vorrang vor den Regeln. (Weil die Regeln die bestehende und sich ständig verändernde Sprache beschreiben. Regeln diktieren nicht, wie die Sprache zu sein hat.)

Daher berufe ich mich auf mein Sprachgefühl, und das sagt mir: Ein *»ist«* wäre nach *»Anwendung«* sicher besser als es auszulassen. Aber der Satz funktioniert auch ohne dieses *»ist«.*

Prinzipiell (und da bin ich dann doch bei den Regeln) ist es ja so, dass Subjekt und Verb im Numerus übereinstimmen müssen. Und hier liegen zwei Hauptsätze vor, die durch ein *und* zusammengefügt sind:

> 1. Alle Funktionen sind schon konfiguriert.
> 2. Die Anwendung ist damit sofort nutzbar.

Bei einer Auslassung dürfen nur solche Wörter weggelassen werden, die genau gleich (und mit gleicher Bedeutung) an anderer Stelle schon in Verwendung sind.

Das wäre also aus sprachlicher Sicht kein Problem, passt nur leider nicht zur Anforderung:

> Alle Funktionen sind schon konfiguriert und die Anwendung**en** damit sofort nutzbar.

Oder auch:

> **Die Funktion ist** schon konfiguriert und die Anwendung damit sofort nutzbar.

Wenn man es genau nimmt, oder wenn man auf sprachliche Schönheit achtet, müsste es daher heißen:

> Alle Funktionen sind schon konfiguriert und die Anwendung ist damit sofort nutzbar.

Das Weglassen des *»ist«* reduziert aber die Verständlichkeit des Satzes nicht, und somit ist die grundlegendste Aufgabe von Sprache, nämlich Informationen von einem Sender zu einem Empfänger zu übertragen, nach wie vor gewährleistet, und aus diesem Blickpunkt heraus ist das Weglassen somit akzeptabel.

Comment: @guidot: Ja, natürlich. Ich habe es auch schon korrigiert. Danke!